# How to use Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I couldn't find any documents about the new version. Versions 7 and 6 have a large number of documents, while 9 is almost nonexistent. Not only me but most people couldn't find it.
I just wanted to send simple notifications to the background. I would be very happy if anyone shared a document about the new version.
Or should I use the old version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you know how to add firebase to your App. If not: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

After adding firebase to the App, this is what I do :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
      '/': (context) =>  AppStarter(),
      '/message': (context) => NotificationDetails(),
      },
     ),
    );
   }



class AppStarter extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
   _AppStarterState createState() => _AppStarterState();
  }



class _AppStarterState extends State<AppStarter>
   {

     FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    Future<void> showMeMyToken()
    async {
      var myToken = await messaging.getToken();
      print("My Token is: " + myToken.toString());
    }


    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();

       showMeMyToken();

      FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) {
       if(value != null)
        {
          Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context){return NotificationDetails();},
          settings: RouteSettings(arguments: value.data,),
         ),
        );
       }
     });


     FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {


        if (message.notification != null) {
           print('Message on Foreground: ${message.notification}');
              }
         });


      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message)
       {
         Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (context) {return NotificationDetails();},
               settings: RouteSettings(arguments: message.data,)
          ),
        );
     });

     FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
   }


   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Just a Test',
        
        home: AppHome(),
       );
      }
   }




   Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
     await Firebase.initializeApp();

      print("Handling a background message :-): ${message.data}");
      //Here you can do what you want with the message :-)
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But i don't understand [NotificationDetails(),] part. I did what you wrote, the token arrived but I couldn't run it. How can i use that  without Navigator.push?

Comment: NotificationDetails() is just a class I created to display the notification. You can call your own class there.

You couldn't run what?

Comment: I did finally works but still have a problem. Notification comes when in background , but not when app is open. This error: 
Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)

Comment: Which function do you have in  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage? In the onMessage, you write what your app should do when the notification arrives while the app is on foreground.

Comment: Actually i don't need onMessage method. Background notification enough for me.

Comment: You can delete the onMessage method if you don't need it

Comment: Yes i deleted it and it works thanks a lot.

Comment: i have the same problem with version ^9.1.3, i need to manage notification click event, but onforeground tap message does not work.
Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed), and  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen is not triggered, my onmessage function only have a print(¨msg¨).

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample app showcasing how to implement the notification system with FCM on version 9.

[You can refer to this project](https://github.com/FDuhen/fcm-cleanarch--flutter) and if you need more informations, I'll edit this answer !

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to add your codes but I couldn't manage.I know Flutter at a basic level. It feels so complicated, like a Nolan movie. I guess i should try to only local notifications. Older versions only sent a notification with a few lines of code.This so hard lol. Thanks again.

Comment: hi, you sample only show onbackground handler that does no have any  issue in version 9 but what about FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen? looks like that the new plugin version 9 have and unresolve issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4261