# handling notification in fcm flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I sent a message to the device via an HTTP POST request like the following:

```
{
"data":{
    "title":"title message",
    "body":"message"
},
"to":"token"}
```

how to display the notification to the user, I've tried something like this: I used the firebase_messaging package: ^ 8.0.0-dev.15

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  Map<String, dynamic> setMessage = message.data;
  if(setMessage != null) {
    showNotification(message.data);
  }
});

void showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
var androidDetails =
AndroidNotificationDetails('1', 'channelName', 'channel Description');

var iosDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();

var generalNotificationDetails =
NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    messaging.hashCode,
    message['title'],
    message['body'],
    generalNotificationDetails,
    payload: 'Notification'
);}
```

Comment: Read this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934956/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging/66935971?noredirect=1#comment118360258_66935971

Comment: @CeltK.B. I want to display the title and body in the data

Comment: send data via rest API:
{
"data":{
    "title":"title message",
    "body":"message"
},
"to":"token"}

response :

{
    "multicast_id": 6429734702570295,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1617693335571719%75785785ccccc"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: In the message.data, you have everything. Try to print message.data to see what is inside. message.data[title] should be the title

Comment: print message.data[title]  Nothing

Comment: @CeltK.B. I tried that on IOS

Comment: Was firebase added to your project for iOS?
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/. On android you don't  need messaging.requestPermission, but on iOS you need it.

Comment: @CeltK.B. after I changed the json format via rest like this:
{
     "notification": {
         "title": "INFO",
         "body": "notif"
     },
     "to": "token"
}

notification appears. but the question is how to display notifications if the json format is like this:

{
     "data":{
         "title": "INFO",
         "body": "notif"
     },
     "to": "token"
}

Comment: I think, the problem could be your showNotification function. Print the raw message and tell me what you get. Try this:
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
print (message.data);
  Map<String, dynamic> setMessage = message.data;
  if(setMessage != null) {
    showNotification(message.data);
  }
});

Comment: just the same doesn't appear in print ()

Comment: if I send it with a format like this:
{"data": {"title": "INFO", "body": "notif"}, "to": "token"}
API responses:
{
     "multicast_id": 6133784157174206024,
     "success": 1,
     "failure": 0,
     "canonical_ids": 0,
     "results": [
         {
             "message_id": "0: 1617700042015680% 73b96235f9fd7ecd"
         }
     ]
}

Comment: print (message.data) nothing

Comment: if the json format is like this:
{
     "data":{
         "title": "INFO",
         "body": "notif 1"
     },
     "notification": {
         "title": "INFO",
         "body": "notif 1"
     },
     "to": "token"
}

There are two notifications that appear

Comment: I don't use localNotification, but I can show data and the notification itself. To see both, I just print print("Notification: ${message.notification.body}");
  print("message: ${message.data}");
I print that in my onMessage function. Try that before this line Map<String, dynamic> setMessage = message.data; and tell me what you see in the console

Comment: Remember that the onMessage is called only when your app is on foreground

Comment: you send notification via rest? what kind of json format do you have?

Comment: try to send a notification like this:
{
     "data":{
         "title": "INFO",
         "body": "Announcement"
     },
     "to": "token"
}

then you print ("message: $ {message.data}"); , I'm sure there's no data printed on the console

Comment: I am simply using the firebase console and I have both, data and notification.

Comment: looks like the firebase console uses the json data format like this:
{"data": {"title": "INFO", "body": "notif 1"}, "notification": {"title": "INFO", "body": "notif 1"}, "to" : "token"}
to be sent to the application